# UIDatePicker available dates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uidatepicker

I know that it's possible to set minimum and maximum date for UIDatePicker. What I want is to set alternating available/not available date ranges (so appropriate rows are active & could be selected or gray and not selectable). Is it possible?

Comment: It would be a very sensible feature to have in the SDK, perhaps you could make a request to apple :) Seems like a difficult one to hack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible with `UIDatePicker`. You'd have to make that yourself with a `UIPickerView`.